# is there any way to install libgranite-dev on mac os?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, elementaryos

I'm trying to get the elementary OS terminal working on mac. The installation process of this terminal is described [here](https://github.com/elementary/terminal).

after downloading the folder with the  code files and typing:

```
meson build --prefix=/usr
```

The following error appears:

```
meson.build:48:0: ERROR: Dependency "granite" not found, tried pkgconfig, framework and cmake
```

I also found [this](https://github.com/elementary/granite) Github site where they explain how to install granite. But at the time of running `ninja` in the terminal inside the build folder i get this other error:

```
lib/libgranite.6.dylib.p/Services/System.c:28:10: fatal error: 'gio/gdesktopappinfo.h' file not found
#include <gio/gdesktopappinfo.h>
```

I haven't found a lot about this error, though on some sites they posted about this while compiling other different packages, but the information i found was like about 4 years ago and nothing mentioned in these posts seems to be useful.

Here are the links to the sites i visited regarding this error:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/55345

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/54424

https://github.com/lxde/libfm/issues/44

I'm totally clueless about what to do so i would like if any one could help me fix this error or tell me if there is actually a way of installing the granite package on mac OS. i saw there is a `libgranite-dev` package available on Linux but i haven't found the way to install this on mac OS either.

Thank you very much in advance.